# python tkinter, Scrollbar missing knob(thumb)

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, scrollbar

【Summary】
By tkinter, python. I set scrollbar on Canvas ... Then that has been succeeded.
But missing knob in scrollbar.

【Background】
This is my application that developing now.
App's purpose is simple. Get some icons from target URL, Then put as tile in Window.

[Application Window graphic](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/we-yu/we-yu.github.io/master/2019/03/28/Line-Sticker-Lider-cooperate-with-Slack/ScrollbarTroubleC.png)

As you see, Can't put all icons in initial window size.
So I want to use scrollbar, Then scrolldown to show below icons.

Now succeeded put scrollbar at right side. But in that bar missing knob(thumb).
So this isn't working as scrollbar (TωT)

【Question】
How to make code to this vertical scrollbar working?

This is scrollbar build section in my src file.
Already exists scrollbar, It's almost fine... But maybe missing something.

```
        # Make vertical scrollbar to see all stickers -----------------------
        outCV = tk.Canvas(self.iconsFrame, width=GUIController.__windowWidth, height=GUIController.__windowHeight)

        scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(self.iconsFrame, orient=tk.VERTICAL)
        scrollbar.config(command=outCV.yview)
        scrollbar.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.Y)

        outCV.configure(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
        outCV.pack()
        # --------------------------------------------------------------------
        gridRow = 0
        gridCol = 0

        for i, tkimg in enumerate(self.tkimgs) :

            # Put icons as tile.
```

Please give me your knowledge.

(FYI) https://github.com/we-yu/L_SL/blob/develop/Canvas_in_Canvas/src/GUICtrl.py Line:196

Comment: It doesn't look like you've configured the `scrollregion`, though it's impossible to say since there's no way to run your code.

Comment: @BryanOakley
Thanks Mr.Bryan. I searched `scrollregion` and continued to investigate how-to about scrollbar and finally I got how to solve. I'm going to post about answer of my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found already how to solve it by myself.
There are 2 points in my case.

1. Should be set `scrollregion`
2. Scrollbar works for only Canvas. So, on my case. Need overlapped frames and canvases.

**Solving way**

```
        self.outerCV = tk.Canvas(self.iconsFrame, width=GUIController.__windowWidth, height=GUIController.__windowHeight)

        scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(self.iconsFrame, orient=tk.VERTICAL)
        scrollbar.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.Y)
        scrollbar.config(command=self.outerCV.yview)

        self.outerCV.config(scrollregion=(0, 0, 2000, 2000), yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
        self.outerCV.pack(fill=tk.BOTH)

        galleryFrame = tk.Frame(self.outerCV)
        self.galleryTag = self.outerCV.create_window((0, 0), window=galleryFrame, anchor=tk.NW, width=self.outerCV.cget('width'))
```

Put Basement-frame at bottom of window. Then put Canvas on that. Scrollbar attaches on this Canvas.
But if put Canvas on this Canvas, Scrollbar works for scroll, But window won't be working.
So, put frame on scrollbar-canvas. Then Main graphic canvases on that frame.

```
[Canvas-1][Canvas-2][Canvas-3]...
[Frame for gallery]
[Canvas for Scrollbar]
[Basement frame]
```